# Starting a Sharepoint 2013 workflow : Something went wrong. To try again, reload the page and then start the workflow

Tags: workflow

As titled , Actually my 2013 workflow was working from last year to last week  , suddenly it prompted error **"Something went wrong. To try again, reload the page and then start the workflow."** yesterday when i click manually or auto start the workflow yesterday. so I start to search to solve the problem.

ULS Log (cause the prompt has not any correlation ID so i think this log is related):

```
 Microsoft.Workflow.Client.InvalidRequestException: The scope '/SharePoint/default/f103806c-7b36-4287-8bd5-18f0369ffdfe/43461f5c-4188-46fa-b438-1647782da25d' has no workflows under it. HTTP headers received from the server - ActivityId: 1298292e-b208-4970-8572-df9d71ae535e. NodeId: AS2HKDIIS11. Scope: /SharePoint/default/f103806c-7b36-4287-8bd5-18f0369ffdfe/43461f5c-4188-46fa-b438-1647782da25d. Client ActivityId : 928b609e-84c8-d0ec-431f-3255393c175b. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.    
 at Microsoft.Workflow.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)    
 at Microsoft.Workflow.Client.HttpGetResponseAsyncResult`1.End(IAsyncResult result)    
 at Microsoft.Workflow.Client.ClientHelpers.SendRequest[T](HttpWebRequest request, T content)     -
 -- End of inner exception stack trace ---    
 at Microsoft.Workflow.Client.ClientHelpers.SendRequest[T](HttpWebRequest request, T content)    
 at Microsoft.Workflow.Client.WorkflowManager.StartInternal(String workflowName, WorkflowStartParameters startParameters)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.FabricWorkflowManagementClient.StartInstance(String serviceGroupName, String workflowName, String monitoringParam, String activationKey, IDictionary`2 payload)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.FabricWorkflowInstanceProvider.StartWorkflow(WorkflowSubscription subscription, IDictionary`2 payload) StackTrace: 
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Native.dll: (sig=678c0f87-966f-4d99-9c94-b49e788d2672|2|microsoft.office.server.native.pdb, offset=131CE)
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Native.dll: (offset=21BE5)
```

[image]

I have already tried :

1. restart service - Workflow Manager Backend
2. restart service - Service Bus Message Broker
3. restart service - Service Bus Gateway
4. restart service - Windows Fabric Host Service
5. recycle Workflow Manager application pool
6. restart WorkflowServiceBackend Service (using cmdlet or manuel)
7. cleared the sharepoint configration cache and restart SP timer service
8. reboot server
9. re-publish SP2013 workflow.
10. try 2010 workflow – it is work 2010 workflow but 2013 workflow is not solve.
11. iis reset
12. flush the DNS cache : cmd "IPCONFIG /FLUSHDNS"
13. Confirm User Profile Service from Central Administration and validated that user synchronizations were still occurring
14. try to Register-SPWorkflowService -SPSite 'https://SiteCollectionURL' -WorkflowHostUri 'http://workflowhost:12991' -AllowOAuthHttp –Force

prompt error :

```
Register-SPWorkflowService : Could not allocate space for object 'dbo.Objects'.'IX_Objects_Version' in database
'SharePoint_Config' because the 'PRIMARY' filegroup is full. Create disk space by deleting unneeded files, dropping objects
in the filegroup, adding additional files to the filegroup, or setting autogrowth on for existing files in the filegroup.
```

Any suggestion. thank you very much.

Search :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj193529(v=azure.10).aspx

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/b7670070-be52-4fa6-bfe2-4d5ca40428a1/something-went-wrong-to-try-again-reload-the-page-and-then-start-the-workflow-error-on-starting-a?forum=sharepointadmin

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/projectserver/en-US/516a9363-b594-4463-b207-1de6b86d5bd3/error-running-sharepoint-2013-workflows-invalidrequestexception?forum=wflmgr

Comment: Oh, I check the SharePoint Content DB storage is full.

Comment: Oh so you found your answer! Great. Please update your comment as an answer so other people might find it useful in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I check the SharePoint Content DB storage is full. 
and then reboot the server.
Everything is resume normal. Tks All